# PHP - Match two strings ignoring span tags

Tags: php, regex, string, match

I am looking for a function that matches string A with string B (ignoring span tags)

```
a) Shopping for <span>Stylish</span> Rugs Area

b) Shopping for Stylish Rugs Area
```

Function should return TRUE if match is found else FALSE, so in above case it should return TRUE.

Thanks

Comment: And what did you try so far? This looks like "do my homework for me".

Comment: Should it ignore other tags as well?

Comment: Thanks for your messages, i am able to sort this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`strip_tags()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to remove the tags from string.

```
$a  = 'Shopping for <span>Stylish</span> Rugs Area';
$b = 'Shopping for Stylish Rugs Area';
var_dump(strip_tags($a) == $b); // outputs true
```